# How to change WebView User-Agent randomly on android app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to change my `WebView` `User-Agent` at every app launch at random order how can I do it?

here is my `WebView` User agents

```
   Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
   Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-us; SM-N900T Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
   Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; de-de; GT-I9300 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
   Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

I want to randomly load `User-Agent` from the list above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple! You can do it through an `array` like this.

```
//Load User agent randomly
  

    val randomuseragent = arrayOf("   Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
        ",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-us; SM-N900T Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
        ",
     "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; de-de; GT-I9300 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
        " ,
     "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRG83) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
        ")
    
     val randomUserAgent = randomuseragent[(Math.random() * randomuseragent.size).toInt()]
            val USER_AGENT =(randomUserAgent)
            /// Set User Agent
            myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);
            ///
```

Comment: the first agent works fine for me